# Why would people Cast Objects

Tags: java, object, casting

While studying the oracle docs I ran into Casting objects and I don't understand the purpose of why people would use it.

so lets say in main you have

```
Person p2 = new Student();
Person p3 = new GraduateStudent();
```

and then you have separate classes

```
class Person
{

}

class Student extends Person
{

}

class GraduateStudent extends Student
{

}
```

I understand that a student is person and that a graduate student is a person 
but why would a person write

```
Person s1 = new Student()
```

instead of

```
Student s1 = new Student()
```

Comment: Consider the reasons why you might ever cast an integer to a float or vice versa.

Comment: The purpose is that sub-classes often have extra methods, and you want to access those methods.  APIs are often made to be general, and will use a super-class.  But you may need to cast to get at methods you know exist.  Examples are casting a `List` to an `ArrayList`, or cast a `Graphics` object to a `Graphics2`.

Comment: What if you also had `class Professor extends Person` and you wanted to send an email to all teachers and students? You could just collect a list of Person instead of keeping separate collections of Student and Professor.

Comment: "but why would a person write `Person s1 = new Student()` instead of `Student s1 = new Student()`" possibly related: [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947)

Comment: Side note: what you describe is _not_ casting but rather simple ploymorphous assignment. Casting would be if you'd later do `Student casted = (Student)s1;`.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you are asking is regarding polymorphous assigning in Java. A very good example that I've heard goes a little something like this:

Say for example you need to generate a payroll for every type of employee in your organization. Without polymorphism, it would be that you would need to have a function for every type of Employee in the organization. For example:
For every Manager, you would need

`public void generatePayroll(Manager manager)`

For an Account employee, you would need

`public void generatePayroll(Accountant accountant)`

So then, you would almost immediately realize that you would be doing some tedious work by applying functionality of generating a payroll to every Employee. Instead, (and thank God for polymorphism), you can have a single method which then just takes in an Employee type since both Accountant and Manager both extend the Employee class. The signature would then change as such:

`public void generatePayroll(Employee employee)`

That way, you will be able to eliminate the need for having a generatePayroll method for every Employee level, and just stick to this one! (Remember, DRY is best!)

Answer (score 0):

```
Person s1 = new Student()
```

means s1 is a Person but maybe you don't need the compiler to know that it's also a Student

after declaring s1, if not final, you can redefine s1 like this :

```
s1 = new GraduateStudent()
```

Imagine, at school you lunch only in a room reserved to students, when people pass their pass card to enter the room, the machine only needs to know if the pass card is valid (i.e belongs to a student), but never search if he is graduated or not.